# What's the best approach to writing a .NET5 WPF that needs to wrap a 3rd-Party DLL requiring System.Web.Services

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dll, .net-5

I think the title sums it up, but I have a 3rd party lib built against .NET Framework v4.6.2. It uses System.Web.Services for SOAP calls. I'd like to update my WPF application to use .NET5, but because support was dropped for System.Web.Services, I find myself stuck.

I've tried a handful of things mostly around .NET Standard (not supported there either), culminating in the desperate copying of the entire v462 Framework into the bin/ folder. I receive a NullReference exception from within System.Web.Services...SoapClient...

Other than creating a separate binary that my main binary talks to, how would you approach it? Is there a way to get it to pull in some of the .NET Framework from a Core or NET5 app?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `System.Web.Services` to make SOAP calls at all. Never did. WCF proxies don't use that class. You can add a Connected Service reference, the same way you could with .NET Old projects

Comment: `System.Web.Services` was used for the ancient ASMX SOAP services that were replaced by WCF in 2008. ASMX didn't support any of the WS-* interoperabilitty standards supported by WCF. The only reason to use ASMX was to call legacy *non-standard* SOAP services

Comment: If all else fails, you can always run the offending dll in a separate processes and some IPC method to talk to it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the issue is with it being a 3rd party lib that I can't control. Would using the 'Connected Service reference' in VS be a way around this? That doesn't make sense to me, but I've never used them.

Comment: If it's a 3rd party library using a 17-year old technology, how do you know it will even run on .NET Core? If it's built for .NET Old only, it probably won't work at all. It should target .NET Standard 2.0